# Google-Webmaster-Tools thorws thousands of Crawling-Errors (503-Error)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-search-console

I just had a look in my google-webmaster-tools and there are over 4.000 crawling-errors, all of them HTTP 503.

Google says, that even the domain-name is a 503 (!?) and I comepletely don't know what to look for.

My robots.txt only blocks some static pages as the contact-form. The htaccess makes some mod-rewrite, and thats it.

Can someone please tell me, what I could try to find out the cause for that 503-behaviour?

Comment: have you looked up what a 503 error actually means?  have you correlated the errors with error lines in you server logs?

Comment: yes, I did both. My server ist watched by Tripwire and there were no downtimes. The Server-logs say, that the googlebot could access a few URLs but the most have a 503

Comment: <sigh> and of the urls that have a 503 for googlebot, do you also get a 503 if you try (from your browser for instance)?  Have you matched the 503 errors in the access log with possible errors in the error log?  You will help yourself (and your standing here) if you try basic debugging yourself.

Comment: Hi, .. I have looked in the .htaccess, robots.txt and also the serverlogs. Everything clear in there. The serverlogs say, that googlebot tried to access the urs with the 503-Error, other urls were accesses successfully by the googlebot. Every url is accessible in the browser. I just can't help me out.